# Implementing Comparator raises ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Java Webservice project using Spring and Primefaces. On Windows machines this runs well and it also ran well on Ubuntu 14. But the error occurs on Ubuntu 16 and also on Debian, although I am not sure if the issue is related to the operation system:

Whenever I have a class that implements Comparator, launching the application raises the following error:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:backend-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/classes/de/xxx/xxx/xxx/web/mapper/JobMapper.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1320
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/lib/project-impl-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/backend-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/classes/de/xxx/xxx/xxx/web/mapper/JobMapper.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1320
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/classes/de/xxx/xxx/xxx/web/mapper/JobMapper.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1320
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/lib/project-impl-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/backend-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/classes/de/xxx/xxx/xxx/web/mapper/JobMapper.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1320
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.handleError(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:239)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/USER/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project-web/WEB-INF/classes/de/xxx/xxx/xxx/web/mapper/JobMapper.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1320
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:262)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1320
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:59)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:239)
    ... 44 more
```

It is always 1320 and I tried with different Java versions ...

Comment: please post also code causing the error, definition of comparator, how you make the call....

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: See if you can reproduce this error in a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would make it a lot easier for everyone to help you. With a little luck you may even stumble on a solution while trying to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, here is what happened:

It was Java and Spring version not working together as mentioned in the comment of the duplicate question. I wrote that I tried with different Java versions, just I forgot that from eclipse Tomcat will not care about the Java version as specified within JAVA_HOME.